# c++ was a system call executed properly

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, system

I have written a small c++ program that takes some input files and runs some ffmpeg processes on them (via the 'system()' function). I would like to add to that program some code to delete the original files but I need to be sure that the ffmpeg commands executed properly and with no errors. How can I get my c++ program to check if the system() function it used executed properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation for [`system`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/)

> If command is not a null pointer, the value returned depends on the
>   system and library implementations, but it is generally expected to be
>   the status code returned by the called command, if supported.

In other words:

```
 if(system("mycommand") != 0) 
 {
     cout << "mycommand failed..." << endl;
 }
```

or something like that. [Obviously assuming that "mycommand" is defined to give a result code of 0 if successfull - most things do, but there are exceptions].

Comment: I have added that into my program and it seems to work well but I'm just not sure if there may be a situation where it fails and still returns 0. Is there somewhere I can lookup a list of ffmpeg's returned status codes? I might make the delete command just move the original file to trash rather than using 'rm' so that I can still retrieve it if I see something has gone wrong.

Comment: @Sam: One would suspect that some documentation for `ffmpeg` does document what the return values are for different success/failure scenarios. But I don't know where you'd find that.